# How to access array result from API in Laravel Blade

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

[image: dd result]
I have an API resulted as in picture. And I want to show the result in Laravel Blade. So I use this code:

```
    @if(isset($data))
        @foreach ($data as $had)
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">#</td>
            dd({{ $had['data']['NoHdt'] }});
            <td>{{ $had['data']['NoHdt'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $had['data']['Kitab'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $had['data']['Isi_Indonesia'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
  </tbody>
```

But it always resulted

> Undefined index: data

How to make it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Thanks to Davit, he gave me the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach ($apiResult['data'] as $data)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">#</td>
        <td>{{ $data['NoHdt'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data['Kitab'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data['Isi_Indonesia'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

where `$apiResult` correspond your shared dd screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQWfi.png

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following instead.

```
@if(isset($data))
@foreach ($data as $had)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">#</td>
    dd({{ $had->NoHdt }});
    <td>{{ $had->NoHdt }}</td>
    <td>{{ $had->Kitab }}</td>
    <td>{{ $had->Isi_Indonesia }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endif
</tbody>
```